# Remove amp; in the list

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove the `amp;` from all the data inside the list
`['?daypartId=1&amp;catId=12', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=1', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=2', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=11', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=10', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=6', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=4', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=14', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=5', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=3', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=8']`

desired output without `amp;`

```
['?daypartId=1&catId=12', '?daypartId=1&catId=1', '?daypartId=1&catId=2', '?daypartId=1&catId=11',...]
```

Comment: Going by the question tags I assume you want to use a regex to do this? Ideally one would use a library which correctly handles this form of escaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub()`:

```
import re

data = ['?daypartId=1&amp;catId=12', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=1', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=2', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=11', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=10', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=6', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=4', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=14', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=5', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=3', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=8']

data = [re.sub(r'amp;', '', item) for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension is best using `replace`

```
my_list=['?daypartId=1&amp;catId=12', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=1', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=2', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=11', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=10', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=6', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=4', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=14', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=5', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=3', '?daypartId=1&amp;catId=8']
[i.replace('&amp;','') for i in my_list]
```

using regex

```
import re
[re.sub('&amp;','',i) for i in my_list]
```

Output

```
['?daypartId=1;catId=12',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=1',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=2',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=11',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=10',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=6',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=4',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=14',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=5',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=3',
 '?daypartId=1;catId=8']
```